# Unable to remove sound output device iShowU from Audio Midi

Tags: catalina, audio

New here but I have searched and gone through various questions and solutions on removing Multiple Output Devices from Audio Midi but I have not had any luck.

I have uninstalled iShowU Audio Capture from my Mac but it still shows up under the "Output Device" and in Audio Midi Setup with no way to remove it. The - button is greyed out. [image]

I followed the steps given in 'How to Remove a Sound Output Device Created by an Application' and a few others but no luck.

I have also removed iShowU kext files but still no joy.

Would appreciate any help.

Using Catalina if needed.

[image]

Comment: Did you uninstall it using their uninstall app? https://support.shinywhitebox.com/hc/en-us/articles/204161529-Uninstalling-iShowU-Audio-Capture

Comment: Yes I used the uninstall app, @Tetsujin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the iShowU app not uninstalling from my laptop, after navigating the web I found an article about this. Please check the manual uninstall by following all these steps and restarting your laptop: [Uninstalling iShowU Audio Capture](https://support.shinywhitebox.com/hc/en-us/articles/204161529-Uninstalling-iShowU-Audio-Capture)

> ##### Manual Uninstall
>
> Delete the following:
>
> ```
> /Library/Extensions/iShowU Audio Capture.kext; or
>
> /System/Library/Extensions/iShowU Audio Capture.kext
> ```
>
> Catalina onwards, it's only in /Library/Extensions/iShowU Audio
> Capture.kext.
>
> In older installs, it could be in either of the locations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/324607)

Answer (score 0):

In menu bar, click on "Go to folder" and enter `/Library/Audio/`. Then, open the "Plug-ins" folder and go to "Hull". Here you should see your device (iShowU). Just remove the folder and restart your Mac for the changes to apply.